# Pixate updateStylesForAllViews not working after updated to PixateFreestyle

Tags: ios, css, pixate

I change css files at code side. 
It was working very well when i use Pixate. 
I updated my dependencies with Freestyle and i use `updateStylesForAllViews` it does not work anymore. i have to restart my application to get things done. 
Any idea ?

```
- (void)applyCurrentTheme
{
    #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR || TARGET_IPAD_SIMULATOR
        PixateFreestyle.currentApplicationStylesheet.monitorChanges = YES;
    #endif

        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:themeFileName
                                                             ofType:@"css"];

        [PixateFreestyle styleSheetFromFilePath:filePath withOrigin:PXStylesheetOriginApplication];

        [PixateFreestyle updateStylesForAllViews];
}
```

Comment: did you solved your problem ?

Comment: yes, you need to change window style `self.window.styleMode = PXStylingNormal;` at `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`